# Dual boot windows 8 with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I had installed Ubuntu with a dual boot mechanism. For some days i was unable to boot into Ubuntu. Windows 8 booted just fine.

After some days when i switched my laptop ON, Ubuntu 14.04 booted up directly. I didn't get a option to choose which OS to boot.

Till now i have been using Ubuntu 14.04 and i never got a option to choose which OS to boot.

Please help

Regards,
Sagar

Comment: Hold <Shift> key while booting to show grub menu. if it was shown, you have to [repair your grub](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Just install Grub Customizer:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer && apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Then there you can select which OS to boot at first.